# how to test generated iphone application on windows

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I'm developing a shopping project using worklight on windows eclipse Juno.
i'm able to run the generated android project by installing android sdk,ADT.
my question is how to run my generated iphone environment application on windows.?

Comment: Xcode is an IDE, not an Eclipse plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

Worklight Studio only generates the Xcode project. In order to run this project, you must use Xcode. Xcode is an IDE developed by Apple and it runs ONLY on Apple's Mac machines. You cannot use Windows to run the Xcode project.

Please do not skip training modules:

- [IBM Worklight Getting Started training modules](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started/#setup)

Get a Mac. Create an Apple ID, login to the Mac App Store and download & install Xcode.
Only then can you open the generated Xcode project to test your application.

Other services will not help if you intend on moving to Production as you will still need to get a Mac in order to produce the .ipa file that you are required to upload to the iOS App Store.

Answer (score 1):

Like Idan Adar already said, Xcode runs only on Mac OS X.

Due to the fact that you need it just for testing purposes, you could use services like [macincloud](http://www.macincloud.com/) so that you can use Xcode without buying hardware. They host Mac OS X machines with preinstalled Xcode environment and Dropbox so you could move your Xcode project to this machine and test your app. There is also an offer to try this service out so maybe that trial period is sufficient for you.